# Get public images with hashtag from Instagram API

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get any photo from any user on `Instagram` with a certain hashtag, but when I go to:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{hashtag}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

I only get my photos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your app is on `sandbox mode` than that explains it.

The behaviour of the request [`/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent) changes to return only tagged posts from sandbox users.
This is also correct for all other API requests; When app is on `sandbox mode`, the API behaves as if the sandbox users are the only users on Instagram.

From the [`documentation`](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/):

> As another example, let's consider an endpoint that returns a list of
>   media: `/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent`.
>   The response returned by this
>   endpoint will contain only media with the given tag, as expected. But
>   instead of returning media from any public Instagram user, it will
>   return only media that belongs to your sandbox users, restricted to
>   the last 20 for each user.

You can use the [`Instagram API console (APIGEE)`](https://apigee.com/console/instagram) to see this request returns public data with a different authentication type.

Also, note that if all your app does is displaying public content from Instagram then `Instagram` would not approve the app outside sandbox mode.

[image]